# The bar in the d3 graph is going out of range and i am not able to select it using a brush

Tags: d3.js

I have created a d3 graph to show the event count per day so the xaxis shows date and y axis shows count. I have also included brush event to filter data accordingly. but the last bar is shown outof range and i am not able to select it using brush. Now how can i make it look proper. I am adding an image of it and code too ... Everything is coming fine except the selection. please help me out. thanku :)[image: The image shows the date graph in which the last bar is outside the range..]

```
var data = document.getElementById('eventCountList').innerHTML;
        flights = JSON.parse(data);
        // Various formatters.
        var formatNumber = d3.format(",d"), formatChange = d3.format("+,d"), formatDate = d3.time
                .format("%B %d, %Y"), formatTime = d3.time
                .format("%I:%M:%S %p");

        // A nest operator, for grouping the flight list.
        var nestByDate = d3.nest().key(function(d) {
            return d3.time.day(d.date);
        });

        // A little coercion, since the CSV is untyped.
        flights.forEach(function(d, i) {
            d.index = i;
            console.log(d.eventTimeGmt);
            d.date = parseDate(String(d.eventTimeGmt));
        });

        // Create the crossfilter for the relevant dimensions and groups.
        var flight = crossfilter(flights), all = flight.groupAll(), date = flight
                .dimension(function(d) {
                    return d.date;
                }), dates = date.group(d3.time.day), second = flight
                .dimension(function(d) {
                    return d.date.getSeconds();
                }), seconds = second.group(Math.floor), minute = flight
                .dimension(function(d) {
                    return d.date.getMinutes() + d.date.getSeconds() / 60;
                }), minutes = minute.group(Math.floor), hour = flight
                .dimension(function(d) {
                    return d.date.getHours() + d.date.getMinutes() / 60;
                }), hours = hour.group(Math.floor);
        var charts = [

                barChart().dimension(second).group(seconds).x(
                        d3.scale.linear().domain([ 0, 60 ]).rangeRound(
                                [ 0, 10 * 60 ])),

                barChart().dimension(minute).group(minutes).x(
                        d3.scale.linear().domain([ 0, 60 ]).rangeRound(
                                [ 0, 10 * 60 ])),

                barChart().dimension(hour).group(hours).x(
                        d3.scale.linear().domain([ 0, 24 ]).rangeRound(
                                [ 0, 10 * 60 ])),

                barChart()
                        .dimension(date)
                        .group(dates)
                        .round(d3.time.hour.round)
                        .x(
                                d3.time
                                        .scale()
                                        .domain(
                                                [
                                                        new Date(
                                                                flights[flights.length - 1].eventTimeGmt
                                                                        .substring(
                                                                                0,
                                                                                4),
                                                                flights[flights.length - 1].eventTimeGmt
                                                                        .substring(
                                                                                5,
                                                                                7) - 1,
                                                                flights[flights.length - 1].eventTimeGmt
                                                                        .substring(
                                                                                8,
                                                                                10)),
                                                        new Date(
                                                                flights[0].eventTimeGmt
                                                                        .substring(
                                                                                0,
                                                                                4),
                                                                flights[0].eventTimeGmt
                                                                        .substring(
                                                                                5,
                                                                                7) - 1,
                                                                flights[0].eventTimeGmt
                                                                        .substring(
                                                                                8,
                                                                                10)) ])
                                        .rangeRound([ 0, 10 * 60 ])) /*.filter(
                                                                                                        [ new Date(2001, 1, 1), new Date(2001, 2, 1) ]) */

        ];

        // Given our array of charts, which we assume are in the same order as the
        // .chart elements in the DOM, bind the charts to the DOM and render them.
        // We also listen to the chart's brush events to update the display.
        var chart = d3.selectAll(".chart").data(charts).each(
                function(chart) {
                    chart.on("brush", renderAll).on("brushend", renderAll);
                });

        // Render the initial lists.
        var list = d3.selectAll(".list").data([ flightList ]);

        // Render the total.
        d3.selectAll("#total").text(formatNumber(flight.size()));

        renderAll();

        // Renders the specified chart or list.
        function render(method) {
            d3.select(this).call(method);
        }

        // Whenever the brush moves, re-rendering everything.
        function renderAll() {
            chart.each(render);
            list.each(render);
            d3.select("#active").text(formatNumber(all.value()));
        }

        // Like d3.time.format, but faster
        //2015-12-28 11:18:32
        function parseDate(d) {
            return new Date(d.substring(0, 4), d.substring(5, 7) - 1, d
                    .substring(8, 10), d.substring(11, 13), d.substring(14,
                    16), d.substring(17, 19));
        }

        window.filter = function(filters) {
            filters.forEach(function(d, i) {
                charts[i].filter(d);
            });
            renderAll();
        };

        window.reset = function(i) {
            charts[i].filter(null);
            window.poll.start();
            renderAll();
        };

        function flightList(div) {
            var flightsByDate = nestByDate.entries(date.top(40));

            div.each(function() {
                var date = d3.select(this).selectAll(".date").data(
                        flightsByDate, function(d) {
                            return d.key;
                        });

                date.enter().append("div").attr("class", "date").append(
                        "div").attr("class", "day").text(function(d) {
                    return formatDate(d.values[0].date);
                });

                date.exit().remove();

                var flight = date.order().selectAll(".flight").data(
                        function(d) {
                            return d.values;
                        }, function(d) {
                            return d.index;
                        });

                var flightEnter = flight.enter().append("div").attr(
                        "class", "flight");

                flightEnter.append("div").attr("class", "time").text(
                        function(d) {
                            return formatTime(d.date);
                        });

                flightEnter.append("div").attr("class", "sourceAddress")
                        .text(function(d) {
                            return d.sourceAddress;
                        });

                flightEnter.append("div").attr("class", "destAddress")
                        .text(function(d) {
                            return d.destAddress;
                        });

                flight.exit().remove();

                flight.order();
            });
        }

        function barChart() {
            if (!barChart.id)
                barChart.id = 0;

            var margin = {
                top : 10,
                right : 10,
                bottom : 20,
                left : 40
            }, x, y = d3.scale.linear().range([ 100, 0 ]), id = barChart.id++, axis = d3.svg
                    .axis().orient("bottom"), yAxisLeft = d3.svg.axis()
                    .scale(y).orient("left"), brush = d3.svg.brush(), brushDirty, dimension, group, round;

            function chart(div) {
                var width = x.range()[1], height = y.range()[0];

                y.domain([ 0, group.top(1)[0].value ]);

                div.each(function() {
                    var div = d3.select(this), g = div.select("g");

                    // Create the skeletal chart.
                    if (g.empty()) {
                        div.select(".title").append("a").attr("href",
                                "javascript:reset(" + id + ")").attr(
                                "class", "reset").text("reset").style(
                                "display", "none");

                        g = div.append("svg").attr("width",
                                width + margin.left + margin.right).attr(
                                "height",
                                height + margin.top + margin.bottom)
                                .append("g").attr(
                                        "transform",
                                        "translate(" + margin.left + ","
                                                + margin.top + ")");

                        g.append("clipPath").attr("id", "clip-" + id)
                                .append("rect").attr("width", width).attr(
                                        "height", height);

                        g.selectAll(".bar").data(
                                [ "background", "foreground" ]).enter()
                                .append("path").attr("class", function(d) {
                                    return d + " bar";
                                }).datum(group.all());

                        g.selectAll(".foreground.bar").attr("clip-path",
                                "url(#clip-" + id + ")");

                        g.append("g").attr("class", "axis").attr(
                                "transform", "translate(0," + height + ")")
                                .call(axis);

                        g.append("g").attr("class", "y axis").attr(
                                "transform", "translate(" + 0 + ")", 0)
                                .call(yAxisLeft);

                        g.append("text").attr(
                                "transform",
                                "rotate(-90 " + margin.left / 1.8 + " "
                                        + height / 2 + ")").style(
                                "text-anchor", "start")
                                .style("fill", "red")
                                .text("no. of events ");

                        /*
                        g.append("text")
                        .attr("transform", "translate(" + (width / 2) + " ," + (height + margin.bottom) + ")")
                        .style("text-anchor", "middle")
                        .text("Date");  */

                        /*  g.append("text")
                            .attr("transform", "rotate(-90)")
                            .attr("y", 0 – margin.left)
                            .attr("x",0 - (height / 2))
                            .attr("dy", "1em")
                            .style("text-anchor", "middle")
                            .text("no. of events"); */

                        // Initialize the brush component with pretty resize handles.
                        var gBrush = g.append("g").attr("class", "brush")
                                .call(brush);
                        gBrush.selectAll("rect").attr("height", height);
                        gBrush.selectAll(".resize").append("path").attr(
                                "d", resizePath);
                    }

                    // Only redraw the brush if set externally.
                    if (brushDirty) {
                        brushDirty = false;
                        g.selectAll(".brush").call(brush);
                        div.select(".title a").style("display",
                                brush.empty() ? "none" : null);
                        if (brush.empty()) {
                            g.selectAll("#clip-" + id + " rect").attr("x",
                                    0).attr("width", width);
                        } else {
                            var extent = brush.extent();
                            g.selectAll("#clip-" + id + " rect").attr("x",
                                    x(extent[0])).attr("width",
                                    x(extent[1]) - x(extent[0]));
                        }
                    }

                    g.selectAll(".bar").attr("d", barPath);
                });

                function barPath(groups) {
                    var path = [], i = -1, n = groups.length, d;
                    while (++i < n) {
                        d = groups[i];
                        path.push("M", x(d.key), ",", height, "V",
                                y(d.value), "h9V", height);
                    }
                    return path.join("");
                }

                function resizePath(d) {
                    var e = +(d == "e"), x = e ? 1 : -1, y = height / 3;
                    return "M" + (.5 * x) + "," + y + "A6,6 0 0 " + e + " "
                            + (6.5 * x) + "," + (y + 6) + "V" + (2 * y - 6)
                            + "A6,6 0 0 " + e + " " + (.5 * x) + ","
                            + (2 * y) + "Z" + "M" + (2.5 * x) + ","
                            + (y + 8) + "V" + (2 * y - 8) + "M" + (4.5 * x)
                            + "," + (y + 8) + "V" + (2 * y - 8);
                }
            }

            brush.on("brushstart.chart", function() {
                window.poll.stop();
                var div = d3.select(this.parentNode.parentNode.parentNode);
                div.select(".title a").style("display", null);
            });

            brush.on("brush.chart",
                    function() {
                        var g = d3.select(this.parentNode), extent = brush
                                .extent();
                        if (round)
                            g.select(".brush").call(
                                    brush
                                            .extent(extent = extent
                                                    .map(round)))
                                    .selectAll(".resize").style("display",
                                            null);
                        g.select("#clip-" + id + " rect").attr("x",
                                x(extent[0])).attr("width",
                                x(extent[1]) - x(extent[0]));
                        dimension.filterRange(extent);
                    });

            brush.on("brushend.chart", function() {
                if (brush.empty()) {
                    var div = d3
                            .select(this.parentNode.parentNode.parentNode);
                    div.select(".title a").style("display", "none");
                    div.select("#clip-" + id + " rect").attr("x", null)
                            .attr("width", "120%");
                    dimension.filterAll();
                }
            });

            chart.margin = function(_) {
                if (!arguments.length)
                    return margin;
                margin = _;
                return chart;
            };

            chart.x = function(_) {
                if (!arguments.length)
                    return x;
                x = _;
                axis.scale(x);
                brush.x(x);
                return chart;
            };

            chart.y = function(_) {
                if (!arguments.length)
                    return y;
                y = _;
                yAxisLeft.scale(y);
                return chart;
            };

            chart.dimension = function(_) {
                if (!arguments.length)
                    return dimension;
                dimension = _;
                return chart;
            };

            chart.filter = function(_) {
                if (_) {
                    brush.extent(_);
                    dimension.filterRange(_);
                } else {
                    brush.clear();
                    dimension.filterAll();
                }
                brushDirty = true;
                return chart;
            };

            chart.group = function(_) {
                if (!arguments.length)
                    return group;
                group = _;
                return chart;
            };

            chart.round = function(_) {
                if (!arguments.length)
                    return round;
                round = _;
                return chart;
            };

            return d3.rebind(chart, brush, "on");
        }
    };
```

Comment: seems like the last record date is incorrect...or may be its outside teh domain you have set...

Comment: I am not able to find the problem.. i have set the domain according to the data's array length so all the data is set from [0]-[last element]. But the last record is outside of range.... should i increase the width etc??

Comment: I got the answer for i added d3.time.day.offset in domain so that it adds one day more...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have added a day as an offset. that solved my problem.below is my code that solved my problem.....
`d3.time.day.offset(new Date(flights[0].eventTimeGmt.substring(0,4)
                            ,flights[0].eventTimeGmt.substring(5,7)-1,
                             flights[0].eventTimeGmt.substring(8,10)), 1)`